# How to navigate from tab to different Page and viceversa in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, url-routing

If i am having One page with 2 tabs. and if from 2nd tab i am navigating to different page. then how to come back to that 2nd tab from navigated page? i am using $StateProvider.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example code and it works well,

```
index.html
----------------
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tabs Directive</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="tabController.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TabController as tab">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(1)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(1)">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(2)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(2)">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(3)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(3)">Tab 3</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(1)">
             <h4>Tab 1</h4>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(2)">
             <h4>Tab 2</h4>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(3)">
             <h4>Tab 3</h4>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
  </body>
</html>

tabController.js
----------------
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('TabController', function () {
        this.tab = 1;

        this.setTab = function (tabId) {
            this.tab = tabId;
        };

        this.isSet = function (tabId) {
            return this.tab === tabId;
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Atul :)

but this solution worked for me.

we can have one flag varibale ilke **"this.isPageVisited=false"** in APPCONTEXT.js file. so that variable will be available throughout the project. so suppose from tab of one page i am going to different page, what i do is i set **isPageVisited=true** via setter method in visted page . so now to come back to tab page again, we check the variable if its true or not. if  it is true we put the "active" class to the tab element.
so that the we can have current tab active from where navigation started.